# How can I render the structure of book in Drupal 8?

Tags: 8

I would like to render a book tree in Drupal 8. I used to use the [Booktree](https://www.drupal.org/project/booktree) module, but there is not yet a port.

How can I render the structure of book in Drupal 8?

- Chapter 1

  - Section A
  - Section B
- Chapter 2

  - Section C
  - Section D

Comment: What is `bookRender()`?

Comment: Line 116 of BookController.php. Should I be looking for another function?

Comment: Lot of things here. You are not extending a class, like `ControllerBase`. Two, you cannot call other class methods as a function as you have, it would need to be `$object->bookRender($args)`. For example, here is the BookController itself: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21book%21src%21Controller%21BookController.php/class/BookController/8.2.x

Comment: I have no clue what is going on in the Book module. Does it provide an API?